# ReactJS/Router/Flux: Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, flux

**Note:** This is a rather long description, so do bear with me. With the number of components that is entailed for a reproducible JSBin or similar implementation, a written description seemed to be a safer and workable choice.

**TL;DR**

In my `Flux(3.1.2)` / `React(15.4.2)`/ `React-Router(3.0.2)` app, i always seem to get the following error/warning *ONLY* when i navigate between routes:

`warning.js:36 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the AllVideos component.`

**My effort**

I researched a bit and most of the information seems to point to it being a case of listened events not being removed. I tried all variations of suggestions but none seem to work.

**Some background information**

My effort is a very simple app being developed mainly to ensure hands-on learning/practice experience since i am quite new to ReactJS.

A `Node`/ `Express` server in the backend serves data (something like a REST endpoint) consumed by my `ReactJS` app aided by `React-router` and `Flux`.

The initial data is stored in an `SQLite` DB that i return back as `JSON` whenever requested. For example on loading the app, i initiate an AJAX call(via `Axios`) to my server to return back a subset of results in JSON which is then stored in my `Flux` store. Stateful components will use this data to manipulate the view as required.

My Routes.js has this structure:

```
const Routes = (props) => ( 
  <Router {...props}>
   <Route component={MainContainer}> 
    <Route path="/" component={App}> 
     <IndexRoute component={Home} />
     <Route path="videos" component={Videos}></Route>
     <Route path="videos/:mediaid" component={MediaDetails} />
   </Route>
   <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
  </Route>
</Router>
);  
export default Routes;
```

**The flow**

The `<MainContainer>` component is a purely layout component that displays a `<TopHeader>` component and a `<Sidebar>` component, both of which i want consistently persistent across all pages. The additional `{this.props.children}` in my `<MainContainer>`(code is provided towards the end of this description) component will pull in my main content which includes components like `<Home>`, `<AllVideos>` etc.

The `<Home>` component(reachable via `localhost:3000`) is currently just placeholder - i am concentrating on the `<AllVideos>` component (reachable via `localhost:3000/videos`) for now. This `<MainContainer>` component triggers an action in `ComponentWillMount()` that fires off an AJAX call that i will then receive in my store. I populate my initial store object and emit a `onChange` event that I listen for in my `<AllVideos>` component

The `<AllVideos>` component has listeners for the initial AJAX call (made in the `<MainContainers>` component as mentioned above) as well as listeners for a `onFilter` event that i emit when certain filters are activated by the user using form elements like dropdowns, inputs, checkboxes etc (in a separate nested component called `<SearchAndFilter>`).

The `<AllVideos>` component has a nested `<Videos>` component(which currently does nothing but passing on props to its nested `<VideosBody>` component).

Inside the nested `<Videos>` component i have a nested `<VideosBody>` component which maps through the videos object received via props and creates several `<VideoCard>` components(to display data per video).

Additionally in the `<Videos>` component, i have a single `<SearchAndFilter>` component (sitting above all the rendered `<VieoCard>` components)that will display a few form elements for some simple client-side filtering of the data/videos.

The `<AllVideos>` nesting is thus:

```
<AllVideos> (listens for the initial AJAX event triggered from a parent component as well as Filter events triggered from a child component, passes props of its state to its nested children)
  <Videos> (currently just relays props received - may do other things later)
    <VideosBody> (uses props to build the videocards via looping through the data)
        <SearchAndFilter /> (onchange of form element values, fire-and-forget actions are triggered that are dispatched to the store where a Filter event is emitted once the processing is done (i use `promises` since there are keydown events)
        <VideoCard /><VideoCard /><VideoCard /><VideoCard /> etc (also has a <Link to> to the <MediaDetails> object
    </VideosBody>
  </Videos>
</AllVideos>
```

When i hit `http://localhost:3000`, the "/" route is activated and the `<Home>` container display fine.

I navigate(`<Link to>`) from the Sidebar to the videos(http://localhost:3000/videos) link which displays the  component(and thus all nested components inside this). It works fine, i see my videos rendered as expected. I attempt to filter the data using the form elements inside the  component. The filteration works but i get the warning/error that i mentioned in the beginning, which in turn points to the onFilter() method as the culprit (i.e the method that triggers when the Filter event is emitted).

When i directly hit `http://localhost:3000/videos`, my  component displays with correct data. My filters work fine and no errors or warnings are emitted. It works just as i want it to.

It seems to be an issue that emerges when i navigate between routes. I logged the `onFilter()` method and noticed that the filter event is triggered by the number of times i have navigated the routes. If i do a `Home > Videos` it gets correctly triggered once. I navigate back to Home and come back to videos and re-initiate the filter and now the `onFilter()` method is now called twice (with twice the errors). This keeps increasing with each navigation performed.

I noticed that the `ComponentWillUnMount()` doesn't seem to fire in any of the effected components when i navigate between videos and anywhere else. This method is where i remove the event listeners. However, the `ComponentWillMount()` and `ComponentDidMount()` seems to fire with each navigation initiated in all the components. A similar issue [is described here (sub-routes)](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1671)

My MainContainer component(for layout):

```
export default class MainContainer extends React.Component{
...
    componentDidMount(){
        CatalogActions.GetCatalog(); //gets my initial AJAX call going
    };
...
render(){
        return(
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <header className="row primary-header">
                <TopHeader />
            </header>
            <aside className="row primary-aside">Aside here </aside>
            <main className="row">
                <Sidebar />
                <div className="col-md-9 no-float">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </main>

        </div>
        );
    };
```

My App component:

```
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props){

    super(props);

    this.state = {

  }
};

...
...

render() {
  return (
    <div>
        {this.props.children}
    </div>
    );
    };
};
```

The AllVideos component:

```
export default class AllVideos extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
           // isVisible: true
             initialDataUpdated:false,
             isFiltered: false,
            "catalog": []
        };
        this.onChange= this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onError=this.onError.bind(this);
        this.onFilter=this.onFilter.bind(this);
        this.onFilterError=this.onFilterError.bind(this);
    };
    componentDidMount(){
        if(CatalogStore.getList().length>0){
            this.setState({
            "catalog": CatalogStore.getList()[0].videos
        })
        }        
        CatalogStore.addChangeListener(this.onChange);
        CatalogStore.addErrorListener(this.onError);
        CatalogStore.addFilterListener(this.onFilter);
        CatalogStore.addFilterErrorListener(this.onFilterError);
    };
    componentWillUnMount(){ //this method never gets called
        CatalogStore.removeChangeListener(this.onChange);
        CatalogStore.removeErrorListener(this.onError);
        CatalogStore.removeFilterListener(this.onFilter);
        CatalogStore.removeFilterListener(this.onFilterError);
    };
    onChange(){
        //This gets triggered after my initial AJAX call(triggered in the MainContainer component) succeeds
    //Works fine and state is set
        this.setState({
            initialDataUpdated: true,
            "catalog": CatalogStore.getList()[0].videos
        })
    };
    onError(str){
        this.setState({
            initialDataUpdated: false,
            "catalog": CatalogStore.getList()[0].videos

        });
    };
    componentWillMount(){        
    };
    onFilter(){//This is the method that the error points to. The setState does seem to work however, but with accumulating warnings and calls (eg 3 calls if i navigate between different components 3 times instead of the correct 1 that happens when i come to the URL directly without any route navigation)
        this.setState({
            //isFiltered: true,
            catalog: CatalogStore.getFilteredData()
        })

    }
    onFilterError(){
        this.setState({
            //isFiltered: false,
            catalog: CatalogStore.getFilteredData()
        })
    }

/*componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        //console.log(this.props);
    };
    shouldComponentUpdate(){
        //return this.state.catalog.length>0
        return true
    }
    componentWillUpdate(){
        //console.log("Will update")
    }    
*/
    render(){

            return(
            <div style={VideosTabStyle}>
                This is the All Videos tab.
                <Videos data={this.state.catalog} />

            </div>
        ); 
    };
```

The Dispatched events received:

```
_videoStore.dispatchToken = CatalogDispatcher.register(function(payload) {
    var action = payload.action;
    switch (action.actionType) {
        case CatalogConstants.GET_INITIAL_DATA:
            _videoStore.list.push(action.data);
            _filteredStore.videos.push(action.data.videos);
            _filteredStore.music.push(action.data.music);
            _filteredStore.pictures.push(action.data.pictures);
            catalogStore.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
            break;
        case CatalogConstants.GET_INITIAL_DATA_ERROR:
            catalogStore.emit(ERROR_EVENT);
            break;
        case CatalogConstants.SEARCH_AND_FILTER_DATA:
            catalogStore.searchFilterData(action.data).then(function() {
              //emits the event after processing - works fine
                catalogStore.emit(FILTER_EVENT);
            },function(err){
                catalogStore.emit(FILTER_ERROR_EVENT);
            });
            break;
        .....
        .....    
        default:
            return true;
    };
});
```

The event emiiters:

```
var catalogStore = Object.assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
    addChangeListener: function(cb) {
        this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, cb);
    },
    removeChangeListener: function(cb) {
        this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, cb);
    },
    addErrorListener: function(cb) {
        this.on(ERROR_EVENT, cb);
    },
    removeErrorListener: function(cb) {
        this.removeListener(ERROR_EVENT, cb);
    },

    addFilterListener: function(cb) {
        this.on(FILTER_EVENT, cb);
    },
    removeFilterListener: function(cb) {
        this.removeListener(FILTER_EVENT, cb);
    },
    addFilterErrorListener: function(cb) {
        this.on(FILTER_ERROR_EVENT, cb);
    },
    removeFilterErrorListener: function(cb) {
        this.removeListener(FILTER_ERROR_EVENT, cb);
    },
    .....
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on phone so I can't do any testing of your code, but what if you lowercased the 'M' in `componentWillUnmount`?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that was the problem indeed. I spent a day and a half trying to figure out this problem. And to think it was just a case of cases :)